# Помогите найти ошибку в коде Java

Tags: java, ооп

```
package com.company;

import com.company.Dragon.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import com.company.com.Gear.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        byte choise;
        String inputName;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("1 - Дракон");
        System.out.println("2 - Викинг");
        System.out.print("Выберите вашего героя: ");
        choise = scan.nextByte();
        System.out.print("Назовите вашего героя: ");
        inputName = scan.nextLine();

        if (choise == 1){
            Dragon1lvl myDragon = new Dragon1lvl(100, 10);
            myDragon.setName(inputName);
            System.out.println("Кол-во здоровья у вашего героя " + myDragon.getDragonHp());
            System.out.println("Кол-во атаки у вашего героя " + myDragon.getDragonAttack());
            System.out.println("Вашего героя зовут: " + myDragon.getDragonName());
        } else if (choise == 2){
            System.out.println("Назовите вашего героя: ");
        }
    }
}
```

Почему когда срабатывает блок

```
System.out.print("Назовите вашего героя: ");
inputName = scan.nextLine();
```

Мне не дают ввести имя моего героя, компилятор просто пропускает и в итоге я не могу ввести имя. Помогите решить проблему.

Comment: почему `byte`, а не `int`?

Comment: Потому что героев будет немного явно не больше 127

Comment: Имя героя у вас на отдельной строке, `nextByte` не считывает символ конца строки. Добавьте после `scan.nextByte` вызов `nextLine` и всё заработает...

Answer (score 2):

Это связано с тем, что метод  `Scanner.nextByte` не читает символ новой строки в вводе, созданном нажатием `Enter`, и поэтому вызов `Scanner.nextLine` возвращает новую строку.

С подобным поведением вы столкнетесь, когда будете использовать `Scanner.nextLine` после `Scanner.next()` или любой другой `Scanner.nextFoo` метода (кроме `nextLine`).

Как вариант решения можно после вызова метода `nextByte` вызвать метод `nextLine`:

```
package com.company;

import com.company.Dragon.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import com.company.com.Gear.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        byte choise;
        String inputName;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("1 - Дракон");
        System.out.println("2 - Викинг");
        System.out.print("Выберите вашего героя: ");
        choise = scan.nextByte();
        scan.nextLine(); // <-- Вот так
        System.out.print("Назовите вашего героя: ");
        inputName = scan.nextLine();

        if (choise == 1){
            Dragon1lvl myDragon = new Dragon1lvl(100, 10);
            myDragon.setName(inputName);
            System.out.println("Кол-во здоровья у вашего героя " + myDragon.getDragonHp());
            System.out.println("Кол-во атаки у вашего героя " + myDragon.getDragonAttack());
            System.out.println("Вашего героя зовут: " + myDragon.getDragonName());
        } else if (choise == 2){
            System.out.println("Назовите вашего героя: ");
        }
    }
}
```

[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo)

Comment: спасибо большое

Comment: @Валера отметьте пожалуйста ответ как правильный нажав на галочку большую) Спасибо)